# Windows 10 mobile BackgroundMediaPlayer don't want work

Tags: windows, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, windows-10, windows-10-mobile

I have a big issue with BackgroundMediaPlayer on Windows 10 mobile but I think that is very similar as API on Windows Phone 8.1. My app works similar as windows 10 sample. But I decided to add small user interface on mainpage where user can easily stop actual music. Problem is that when I am trying access BackgroundMediaPlayer.Current with events my music player don't play any music but when I delete events from main page It start works again. I manage my music player from other page. Is some way how to find out if my BackgroundMediaPlayer actualy playing some music with name of music ? Because I do not know how to continue with my project... Thanks for help

[image: Quick PLayer]

Comment: The MediaPlayer instance doesn't provide the way to get the name of current playing music, we have to manage it by ourselves. Try to provide more details on the code you used on mainpage and otherpage, what kind of event you delete will make it work. At the same time, check the official sample(scenario1) on GitHub and see if you can find something you missed. https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/714722f53c3ae270f634f54cb2740411f6b11032/Samples/BackgroundAudio

Comment: I have worked with BackgroundPlayer and I have everything working, however I didn't get your question. Can you please post your code

Comment: Hello... If everything works for you I have different question. Ia have problem that I cannot play song from internal storage but I can play them from SD card... I try solve this problem here and maybe you will be able to help me [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/caa815a4-06a8-457c-86e3-5743e4b7762f/uwp-windows-10-background-media-player?forum=wpdevelop)

Comment: Can you please write down your codes here, maybe i would be able to help. I am playing songs from internal storage doing all manipulations (previous, next, pause and play at background).

Comment: @ARH Ok but my code I really big so I decided to make a small description of how I try to play sounds. [link here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-WJjQ5-OCys&feature=youtu.be) I'm sorry for my english and also for quality of sound but there is explained how I try to play my files.